# Read a .txt File into a MATLAB matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a .out file (.txt) in the form:

```
This is a text file
This file was created by Andrew on 4/5/14

Certificate Result Test #12

Time     A     B     C     D    
50       4     3     8     9
55       4     8     7     4
60       8     4     1     4
65       7     1     5     1
70       4     2     2     2
```

How do I read the numbers in the table into a matrix, called M, in MATLAB whilst ignoring all the text at the start?

I have tried using fscan and M = dlmread(filename) but I recieve errors saying Mismatch between file and format string due to the lines of text at the start.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for giving a sample to your question. If you did try different approaches like `fscan` or `dlmread` please include them in your post. The solution may be an easy fix to your code rather than having to write something from scratch. As a pointer, you can also look at the [textscan](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) command and look at the `HeaderLines` parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `textscan` with the `'HeaderLines'` option:

```
fid = fopen('my_file.out'); % or whatever your file is called
M = textscan(fid,'%d %d %d %d %d','HeaderLines',7); % using int32 data types, change as required
fclose(fid)
```

Note that `M` is a cell array

Answer (score 0):

textscan is a powerful tool, with good low level functions. There is also the more convenient 'importdata' which works for many files of this kind:

```
m = importdata('my.txt', ' ', 6)
m =

      data: [5x5 double]
  textdata: {6x5 cell}
colheaders: {'Time'  'A'  'B'  'C'  'D'}
```

As you can see, it not only returns the data in m.data, but you also get the column headers for free.